# Pandas apply tuple unpack function on multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, tuples, apply

Given a `function` that takes multiple arguments and returns multiple values as so:

```
def tuple_unpack(value, another_value):
  ''' does some interesting stuff ... '''
   return value, another_value
```

Is there a way to apply such function to a `pandas` `dataframe` where for the 2 function arguments I can pass values from 2 columns, then unpack the output tuple on multiple colums as so:

```
df[['value_col','another_value_col']] = df.apply(lambda df.col, df.col: tuple_unpack)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can using `concat` , with dataframe constructor

```
unpackdf=pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x : tuple_unpack(x.col_1,x.col_2),1).tolist(),columns=['col1','col2'],index=df.index)
yourdf=pd.concat([unpackdf,df],axis=1)
```

Comment: I would hope there'd be a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following

```
df['value_col'], df['another_value_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: tuple_unpack(x.col_1, x.col_2), axis=1, result_type='expand').T.values
```