# Unpacking a tuple on multiple columns of a dataframe from Series.apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I came across this problem at work today and I would like to know if there is an efficient way to do this.

Basically I have a dataframe which look like this

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], columns = ['a'])
```

I also have a function that returns a tuple.
(Make note that this is only a minimal example, my problem is different)

```py
compute = lambda x: (2*x, 3*x)
```

I need to find a way to do something that would ideally look like this:

```py
(df['b'], df['c']) = df['a'].apply(compute)
```

Unfortunately, this syntax doesn't work and I can't wrap my head around another way to do it.

The only similar problem is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52876635/pandas-apply-tuple-unpack-function-on-multiple-columns)
, but the solution seems really 'hacky' and I am convinced there is a better way to do it.

Thank you!!

Comment: Could do something like `df['b'], df['c'] = zip(*df['a'].map(compute))`, but it will probably be slower than just using a vectorized method to create each.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIUC, you can try with:

```
compute = lambda x: (2*x, 3*x)
df[['b','c']]=pd.DataFrame(df.a.apply(compute).tolist()) #thanks harvpan
#df[['b','c']]=pd.DataFrame(df.a.apply(compute).values.tolist())
print(df)
```

---

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  4  6
2  3  6  9
```

Comment: Just `pd.DataFrame(df['a'].apply(compute).to_list())` would do.

Answer (score 3):

Another way

```
df=df.reindex(columns=df.columns.tolist()+['b','c'])
df[['b','c']]=list(map(compute,df.a))
df
Out[107]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  4  6
2  3  6  9
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way

```
df[['b','c']] = df['a'].apply(compute).tolist()
```